# Speed up parsing Twitter from json to csv (python)

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter

This is my first post so please bear with me.

I have a large (~1GB) json file of Tweets I collected via Twitter's Streaming API. I am able to successfully parse this out into a CSV with the fields I need, however, it is painfully slow - even with the few entities I am extracting (userid, lat/long, and parsing Twitter date string to date/time). What methods could I potentially use to try and speed this up? It currently takes several hours, and I'm anticipating collecting more data....

```
import ujson
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
from csv import writer
import time

def hms_string(sec_elapsed):
    h = int(sec_elapsed / (60 * 60))
    m = int((sec_elapsed % (60 * 60)) / 60)
    s = sec_elapsed % 60.
    return "{}:{:>02}:{:>05.2f}".format(h, m, s)

start_time = time.time()

with open('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_raw_tweets1.json', 'r') as in_file, \
 open('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets1.csv', 'w') as out_file:

print >> out_file, 'user_id,timestamp,latitude,longitude'
csv = writer(out_file)
tweets_count = 0

for line in in_file:
    tweets_count += 1
    tweets = ujson.loads(line)
    timestamp = []
    lats = ''
    longs = ''

    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet = tweets
        from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
        to_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
        times = tweet['created_at']
        for tweet in tweets:
            times = tweets['created_at']
            utc = datetime.strptime(times, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
            utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone) #comment out to parse to utc
            est = utc.astimezone(to_zone) #comment out to parse to utc
            timestamp = est.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')  # use %p to differentiate AM/PM

    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweets['geo'] and tweets['geo']['coordinates'][0]:
            lats, longs = tweets['geo']['coordinates'][:2]
        else:
            pass

    row = (
        tweets['user']['id'],
        timestamp,
        lats,
        longs
        )

    values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
    csv.writerow(values)

end_time = time.time()
print "{} to execute this".format(hms_string(end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: Why to have an inner iteration over `tweets` while you are iterating over it already?

Comment: Honestly, probably just user error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I may have solved this. Looking at the code I was actually running, it looks like my if/else statement below was incorrect.

```
for tweet in tweets:
        if tweets['geo'] and tweets['geo']['coordinates'][0]:
            lats, longs = tweets['geo']['coordinates'][:2]
        else:
            None
```

I was using else: None, when I should've been using pass or continue. Also, I removed the inner iteration in tweets in my original code. It was able to parse a 60mb file about 4 minutes. Still, if anyone has any tips for making this any faster, I'm open to your suggestions.

**Edit:** I also used `ujson` which has significantly increased the speed of loading/dumping the json data from twitter.